The speech generated by Google Text-to-Speech has background noise that sounds like a mouse click
I development an AI voice assistant project with TTS feature use Google Text to Speech. However synthesizeSpeech's ouput  contain background noise like a mouse click.
Has anyone had a similar problem or is there any workaround for this problem. Thanks a lot.
This is current config.
            const request = {
                input: { text: text },
                voice: {
                    languageCode: "en-US",
                    name: "en-US-Studio-O",
                    ssmlGender: protos.google.cloud.texttospeech.v1.SsmlVoiceGender.FEMALE
                },
                audioConfig: {
                    audioEncoding: protos.google.cloud.texttospeech.v1.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
                    sampleRateHertz: 24000,
                    effectsProfileId: ['handset-class-device'],
                    speakingRate: 1.45
                },
            };

            const [response] = await this.client.synthesizeSpeech(request);

Audio sample: https://jmp.sh/s/SQM0UJsOBlGikL5aFuJG
I tried with other params config about audioEncoding, sampleRateHertz, effectsProfileId however it still error.
Update 28/4: The specific reason is that the current code segment for decoding audio using on AudioWorkletNode, if the audio input is encoded by pcm 16 bit (Azure Speech, ElevenLab support this encoding with Google TTS not), it works fine, but when decoding audio input encoded by Linear16 (Google support), it produces click noise. Is there any solution to this issue? Thanks.
Setup AudioWorkletNode:
      const blob = new Blob([workletCode], { type: "application/javascript" });
      const blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      await this.audioContext.audioWorklet.addModule(blobURL);
      this.audioNode = new AudioWorkletNode(
        this.audioContext,
        "capture-and-playback-processor"
      );

Custome workletCode:
export const workletCode = `
class captureAndPlaybackProcessor extends AudioWorkletProcessor {
    audioData = [];
    index = 0;
    isTalking = false;
  
    constructor() {
      super();
      //set listener to receive audio data, data is float32 array.
      this.port.onmessage = (e) => {
        if (e.data === "clear") {
          // Clear all buffer.
          this.audioData = [];
          this.index = 0;
          if (this.isTalking) {
            this.isTalking = false;
            this.port.postMessage("agent_stop_talking");
          }
        } else if (e.data.length > 0) {
          this.audioData.push(this.convertUint8ToFloat32(e.data));
          if (!this.isTalking) {
            this.isTalking = true;
            this.port.postMessage("agent_start_talking");
          }
        }
      };
    }
  
    convertUint8ToFloat32(array) {
      const targetArray = new Float32Array(array.byteLength / 2);
    
      // A DataView is used to read our 16-bit little-endian samples out of the Uint8Array buffer
      const sourceDataView = new DataView(array.buffer);
    
      // Loop through, get values, and divide by 32,768
      for (let i = 0; i < targetArray.length; i++) {
        targetArray[i] = sourceDataView.getInt16(i * 2, true) / Math.pow(2, 16 - 1);
      }
      return targetArray;
    }
  
    convertFloat32ToUint8(array) {
      const buffer = new ArrayBuffer(array.length * 2);
      const view = new DataView(buffer);
    
      for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        const value = array[i] * 32768;
        view.setInt16(i * 2, value, true); // true for little-endian
      }
    
      return new Uint8Array(buffer);
    }
  
    process(inputs, outputs, parameters) {
      // Capture
      const input = inputs[0];
      const inputChannel1 = input[0];
      const inputChannel2 = input[1];
      this.port.postMessage(["capture", this.convertFloat32ToUint8(inputChannel1)]);
  
      // Playback
      const output = outputs[0];
      const outputChannel1 = output[0];
      const outputChannel2 = output[1];
      // start playback.
      for (let i = 0; i < outputChannel1.length; ++i) {
        if (this.audioData.length > 0) {
          outputChannel1[i] = this.audioData[0][this.index];
          outputChannel2[i] = this.audioData[0][this.index];
          this.index++;
          if (this.index == this.audioData[0].length) {
            this.audioData.shift();
            this.index = 0;
          }
        } else {
          outputChannel1[i] = 0;
          outputChannel2[i] = 0;
        }
      }

      this.port.postMessage(["playback", this.convertFloat32ToUint8(outputChannel1)]);
      if (!this.audioData.length && this.isTalking) {
        this.isTalking = false;
        this.port.postMessage("agent_stop_talking");
        this.port.postMessage(outputChannel1);
      }
  
      return true;
    }
  }
  
  registerProcessor(
    "capture-and-playback-processor",
    captureAndPlaybackProcessor,
  );
`;


Usage:
 this.audioNode.port.postMessage(audio);

